# import multiple csv files from github folder - Python - COVID-19

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to do two things here:

1. Import all the .csv files and add them up to a df.
2. Update the df with the latest file uploaded.

I have been able to import one .csv with:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-22-2020.csv' 
pd.read_csv(url).fillna(0)
```

I could import all the `.csv` files one per one (or with a loop if I knew how to extract all the `.csv` filenames), but there should be a more efficient way. Once I have the df, to "update" it I would:

1. Extract all the `.csv` filenames.
2. Check if all of them are in the df (with the date column). If one is missing, add the missing .csv file to the df.

The problems I'm having are: (a) how can I make scalable the way to extract all the .csv files? and (b) is there any way to extract ONLY the filenames that end with `.csv` from the github folder? In order to do (2) of above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

Comment: Noup, because the files are in the web. The main problem is extracting the filenames ending with `.csv` from the folder in the web. All the solutions below assume the folder is local, when it's in the web.

Comment: I too am trying to solve this mystery

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the `csv` files by this:

```
import glob

csvfiles = glob.glob("/path/to/foder/*.csv")
```

After you have all the `csv` file path, now you can loop over it and read it to a `df`, check if a column is missing or any other kind

Comment: This answer does not seem to work. I just get an empty list instead of the names of the .csv files that I need.

Comment: @Geonerd because the path you gave has no csv files :)

Answer (score 1):

I am still trying to find a better solution but below is a workaround that I use with my code to pull from a github directory. Unfortunately, I still have not found a way to just get a list of CSVs in the github directoy like you can if it was on a local drive.

```
def read_multi_csv(start_year,end_year):     
    years = list(range(start_year,end_year+1))     
    dfs = []
    for YYYY in years:         
        file = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/project/main/data/normalized/'+str(YYYY)+'_crimes_byState.csv'             
        #print (file)         
        df = pd.read_csv(file)         
        dfs.append(df)
    all_dfs = df.concat(df)         
    return all_dfs  

read_multi_csv(2013,2019)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest u use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob), as it provides, IMHO, an easier way to deal with files:

```
from pathlib import Path 
files = Path(folder containing files)
#filter for only csv files
csv_only = files.rglob('*.csv')
#read ur csv files using a list comprehension
#u can attach the filename if it is relevant and makes sense
#by using the stem function from pathlib
combo = [pd.read_csv(f)
         .assign(f.stem)
         .fillna(0)
         for f in csv_only]

#u can lump them all into one dataframe, using pandas' concat function:

 one_df = pd.concat(combo,ignore_index=True)

#u can remove duplicates :

one_df = one_df.drop_duplicates('date')
```